# changing the return value of PromiseKit's recover

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

I want to use `CLGeocoder` and `always` produce a `CLLocation`, whether the geocode call fails or not.

Unfortunately, you can't get a value to `always` without capturing an outside variable, and putting `recover` directly after the geocode call requires that `recover` returns either a `CLPlacemark` or `Promise<CLPlacemark>`, which requires that I unnecessarily create a `CLPlacemark` just to produce a default `CLLocation` that I already have.

```
// build error because recover's return type must be the same as geocode's
CLGeocoder().geocode(postalCode).recover { error -> CLLocation in
```

Currently, I have this workaround:

```
CLGeocoder().geocode(postalCode)
                    .then { placemark -> CLLocation in
                        guard let location = placemark.location else {
                            throw GeocodeError
                        }
                        return location
                    }
                    .recover { error -> CLLocation in
                        // ... make a default CLLocation
                        return defaultLocation
                    }
                    .then { location -> Void in // this is like an always
                        // handle location
                    }
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Is `recover` guaranteed to be called if the `geocode` promise fails but is not chained directly after it?